# Hex characters showing instead of unicode on Ubuntu 22.04 (XFCE)

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, fonts, xfce, unicode

I was trying to fix an issue I had with Libreoffice not displaying certain fonts properly, and when I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/689635/497591), every character turned into a square, which a reset fixed.

Since then, unicode characters have appeared as hex boxes, despite not changing fonts. Here are some examples.
[image: Korean Characters as squares]
[image: Wikipedia characters as squares]
[image: Arabic characters as squares]

I tried to undo the change I did above, but it didn't make any difference.

What do I do?

Comment: Which command did you use to change permissions?

Comment: I used "sudo chmod"

Comment: I meant to ask you to show the complete, exact command.

Comment: Sudo chmod 744 /usr/share/fonts/

Comment: That was not so good. Try: `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/fonts`

Comment: I reported the answer, from where you got the idea. That answer is pure crap IMNSHO.

Comment: That solution worked, than you so much!